# Connecting to Oracle 12 on remote server using Python 2.7.12 results into ORA-12170

Tags: oracle, python-2.7

Both databases are on remote server and I can get connected to and query on them using TOAD. 
When connecting to database configured with OraClient11g_Home1 from Python on my desktop the connection is established successfully. However, trying to connect to database which is using OraClient12Home1 results into ORA-12170 error,i.e. TNS: Connect timeout occurred. Below are configurations.

Edited to contain more information:

I connect to the database using a remote desktop connection. The code is written to automate part of my testing activities by querying two databases and checking whether a single command has been successful on multiple systems(e.g. Ericsson and Huawei)
Output of one query is the input to another one (I can get output from the 11g DB and have previously wrote scripts for it, but this is the first time we're getting connected to the DB on Ora12 using python. I can access both DBs using TOAD on the remote desktop or connect and query 11g DB using python on my desktop but Ora12 throws time out for the same code.

the connection part of the code and how they are queried is as below:

```
#Get chrono number, action code and status from provisioning table
    ip = '********'
    port = *****
    service_name = '*****'
    dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, service_name)
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect("********","********",dsn)
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    totalChronoList = list()
    myQuery=list()
    inputData = list()

    myQuery = ("select CHRONO_NUM_N, ACTION_CODE_V, STATUS_V from gsm_subs_provisioning where ACTION_DT_DT > SYSDATE - 2 order by ACTION_DT_DT desc")


    cursor.execute(myQuery)
    inputData.append(cursor.fetchall())
```

The configurations are as below:

```
 OraClient11g_home1 (11.2.0.1)
        ORACLE_HOME:C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1
        ORACLE_HOME_NAME:OraClient11g_home1
        ORACLE_HOME_KEY:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1
        ORACLE_SID:
        NLS_LANG:AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252
        SQLPATH:C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\dbs
        LOCAL:
        Client DLL:C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\oci.dll
        TNSNames.ora:C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\Network\Admin\tnsnames.ora
        SQLNet.ora:C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\Network\Admin\sqlnet.ora
        LDAP.ora:C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\Network\Admin\ldap.ora
        Login.sql:
        GLogin.sql:
        In system PATH:Yes
        Home is valid:Yes
    OraClient12Home1 (12.1.0.2)
        ORACLE_HOME:E:\app\client\Oracle\product\12.1.0\client_1
        ORACLE_HOME_NAME:OraClient12Home1
        ORACLE_HOME_KEY:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient12Home1
        ORACLE_SID:
        NLS_LANG:AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252
        SQLPATH:E:\app\client\Oracle\product\12.1.0\client_1\dbs
        LOCAL:
        Client DLL:E:\app\client\Oracle\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin\oci.dll
        TNSNames.ora:
        SQLNet.ora:E:\app\client\Oracle\product\12.1.0\client_1\Network\Admin\sqlnet.ora
        LDAP.ora:
        Login.sql:
        GLogin.sql:E:\app\client\Oracle\product\12.1.0\client_1\sqlplus\admin\glogin.sql
        In system PATH:Yes
        Home is valid:Yes
```

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: I've added more information. Let me know if anything else is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred means you can't access the host and/or port of the DB. I bet in your case it is some restriction on firewalls (most reason, but may be others). First of all try to check is the port accessible. Easiest way - run powershell statement:

```
Test-NetConnection <host-or-ip> -port <port>
```

Then go with findings to sysadmin/dba.

**Update:** As you connect to DB using easy access method (ip, port, service name), you don’t have to care about tnsnames.ora.

Comment: Thanks KJIT, you're absolutely right. I cannot ping nor can I run Test-NetConnection on the server with Ora12 from my desktop but I could ping and run Test-NetConnection on the other server. I'll inform the DBA with this.

Answer (score 0):

In your 12c client we can see that no tnsnames.ora file is found.
Copy this file from the 11g client directory.

Comment: Thanks Cyrille, I've set tns_admin to product\12.1.0\client_1\, and created a file with ****=
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ******)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = ****)
    )
  )      but this has not solved the issue. I've sent an Email to our DBA asking them to set the configuration

Comment: the standard path would be : product\12.1.0\client_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
Does it work now?

Comment: This is where I've created the file and the environment variable path is set to the same:   \product\12.1.0\client_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora         The content of the file is as mentioned in my previous comment. I've also tried putting the file inside Client1 folder and changed the path to it but that didn't work either.

Comment: we are missing information, how exactly do you connect to the database? what is you code, command? where does the output provided comes from?

Comment: I've edited my question to contain more information.

Comment: Did the addition of th tnsnames.ora file fixed the missing path in the 12c output?

Comment: On my desktop I've added the file and put the path but it didn't solve the issue. On the remote desktop I can open the path of 11g but when trying to paste the file in the location for Ora12 I get permission denied. I've requested the admin to put it there and I'll update you if it resolved the issue. Thanks, you've been very helpful and patient.

Comment: They've added it :     TNSNames.ora:E:\app\client\Oracle\product\12.1.0\client_1\Network\Admin\tnsnames.ora      I'm still getting the same error. It might be a privilege issue, so I've raised a request to be granted access from my desktop to the given server without having to go through the Remote Desktop.I'll update if it works.

Comment: I've requested the IP to be added to my VPN, and to be granted the same privileges on the server as I had on the other one and the issue has been resolved. Thanks everyone for your help.